# Make an element sticky when the parent scrolls

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an element stick to the bottom of the parent div even when there is nothing above it.
As you can see in [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKrT6.png) [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyb16.png) pictures, the element I'm talking about is the div that contains the textarea.
When there are enough messages in the div above the textarea, it sticks to the bottom of the page just fine, however when there aren't that many elements, it doesn't, even though I've set bottom: 0px;.

Here's a part of the code:

```css
* {

    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.wrapper {

    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 0.8fr 4fr 15fr;
    grid-template-rows: 50px calc(100vh - 65px);
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.navbar {

    grid-column: 1/4;
    background: #223;
}


.main-panel {

    display: none;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    background: #223;

}


.buttons {

    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    background: #456;

}


.screen {

    grid-column: 3/4;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    background: #223;
}




.left-panel {

    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    background: #243;
}




/*css for the chat box*/

.messages {

    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    
}



.message {

    border: 2px solid #dedede;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    
}


.sender {

    font-size: 0.8em;
}



.message-mine {

    border: 2px solid #dedede;
    background-color: #321;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0;

}


.my-messages {

    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    
}




.chat-box {

    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}




.chat-sending-area {


    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr;
    border: 5px solid black;
    background: gray;
    position: sticky;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    height: 6%;
}


.chat-history {

}





.text-area {

    grid-row:1/2;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    width: 95%;
    height: calc(100% - 3px);
    resize: none;
}


.send-button {

    grid-row:1/2;
    grid-column: 2/3; 
}


.send-message-button {

    width: 85%;
    height: calc(100% - 6px);
    border: 3px outset pink;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navbar">
            STUFF HERE.
        </div>
        <div class="main-panel">
            STUFF HERE.
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            STUFF HERE.
        </div>
        <div class="screen">
            STUFF HERE.
        </div>
        <div class="left-panel">
        <div class="chat-box">
                <div class="chat-history">
                    <div class="my-messages">
                        <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-messages">
                        <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="messages">
                        <!--  -->
                        <div class="message" id="message1">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="messages">
                        <!--  -->
                        <div class="message" id="message1">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="chat-sending-area">
                    <div class="send-button">
                        <img class="send-message-button" src="chat-dots.svg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-box">
                        <textarea class="text-area">Write your message here...</textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

I would like the (chat-sending-area) div to stick to the bottom of the (chat-box) div no matter what.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` to `.chat-box` then add `margin-top: auto` to `.chat-sending-area` to solve your problem.

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 0.8fr 4fr 15fr;
    grid-template-rows: 50px calc(100vh - 65px);
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.navbar {
    grid-column: 1/4;
    background: #223;
}

.main-panel {
    display: none;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    background: #223;
}

.screen {
    grid-column: 3/4;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    background: #223;
}

.left-panel {
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    background: #243;
}

/*css for the chat box*/

.messages {
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 35px;
}

.message {
    border: 2px solid #dedede;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.sender {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.message-mine {
    border: 2px solid #dedede;
    background-color: #321;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.my-messages {
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 35px;
}

.chat-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.chat-sending-area {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr;
    border: 5px solid black;
    background: gray;
    position: sticky;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    height: 6%;
}

.chat-history {}

.text-area {
    grid-row: 1/2;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    width: 95%;
    height: calc(100% - 3px);
    resize: none;
}

.send-button {
    grid-row: 1/2;
    grid-column: 2/3;
}

.send-message-button {
    width: 85%;
    height: calc(100% - 6px);
    border: 3px outset pink;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navbar">
            STUFF HERE.
        </div>
        <div class="main-panel">
            STUFF HERE.
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            STUFF HERE.
        </div>
        <div class="screen">
            STUFF HERE.
        </div>
        <div class="left-panel">
        <div class="chat-box">
                <div class="chat-history">
                    <div class="my-messages">
                        <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-messages">
                        <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="messages">
                        <!--  -->
                        <div class="message" id="message1">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="messages">
                        <!--  -->
                        <div class="message" id="message1">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="chat-sending-area">
                    <div class="send-button">
                        <img class="send-message-button" src="chat-dots.svg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-box">
                        <textarea class="text-area">Write your message here...</textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've been trying to fix this for hours! Thank you!